# Can't escape back tick from string error when bind rows in spark data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apache-spark, sparklyr

When running sparklyr::sdf_bind_rows on spark dataframes in R environment I get this error:
Can't escape back tick from string.
I made sure to remove any '`' from the tables.
Sometimes when I perform this twice the second time succeeds.
Any idea?